# How do i install dotnet core from a downloaded script when i need to enable Tls1.2?

Tags: powershell, .net-core, tls1.2

I have a CI/CD script which installs dotnet core using the scripts (https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1).  We download (and cache) the script, then want to invoke it directly from script using powershell

```
powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File "%MYDIR%\dotnet-install.ps1" -Version 2.1.806
```

However, on the CI/CD machine, this fails:

```
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetcli.[snip]/dotnet-sdk-2.1.806-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.[snip]/dotnet-sdk-2.1.806-win-x86.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetcli.[snip]/dotnet-dev-win-x86.2.1.806.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.[snip]/dotnet-dev-win-x86.2.1.806.zip
Could not find/download: ".NET Core SDK" with version = 2.1.806
```

It turns out that this fails because we cannot establish a secure connection, and need to enable Tls1.2

How do I do modify my powershell command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple examples of invoking the file directly from the downloaded file. eg: on the official documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script):

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; &([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1'))) <additional install-script args>"
```

However, I was unable to find any examples of doing this directly from a locally downloaded/cached file.  If you need a local file invoked with TLS 1.2, try this:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; . '%MYDIR%\dotnet-install.ps1'" -Version 2.1.806
```